# Socket problem on Debian 9 - How to use bash script to check

Tags: bash, sockets, debian

I have a service on Debian 9. I also have a bash restarter so if the service shuts down unexpectedly, the restarter will make it run again.

The restarter basically does:

```
if (this service is not running); then
  run service
fi
```

The problem I have is that sometimes, after the service shuts down unexpectedly, the restarter makes it run again but I get the error:

> failed to bind socket acceptor

The service is running but not really working.

What can I add on my restarter so it checks the socket is available first and then, run the service? I am trying a lot of things posted here but nothing works so far.

Comment: Best case scenario would probably be, if you could reproduce the problem with a minimal test case. That is create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. But it might not be possible in your case.

Comment: It is not possible.
Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is probably caused by a connection in `TIME_WAIT` state (see e.g. [here](https://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/addrinuse.html)).

You can avoid this problem by using `SO_REUSEADDR` in the application.

If you can not alter the application you would have to check for this condition in the *restarter* and delay service start until the `TIME_WAIT` connection vanishes.

This check can be done by analyzing the output of `netstat`, e.g.:

```
while netstat -n | egrep ':5678.*:.*TIME_WAIT' >/dev/null ; do sleep 0.1 ; done
```

Where `5678` is your service port number.

Good luck!

EDIT> Restarter snippet with a check:

```
pidof service >/dev/null
PID1=$?
if [ $PID1 -eq 1 ] ; then
    while netstat -n | egrep ':5678.*:.*TIME_WAIT' >/dev/null ; do sleep 1 ; done
    screen -A -dmS service1 gdb --batch -x /home/server/crashreport.gdb /home/server/bin/service
fi
```

Note that a shorter form is possible:

```
if ! pidof service >/dev/null ; then
    while netstat -n | egrep ':5678.*:.*TIME_WAIT' >/dev/null ; do sleep 1 ; done
    screen -A -dmS service1 gdb --batch -x /home/server/crashreport.gdb /home/server/bin/service
fi
```

If your restarter runs this check in a loop you should give screen and gdb its time to start the service (otherwise the service could be run two times which might cause a similar error message as the one in your question...)

Comment: Thank you a lot!
How can I give you points for your answer? I am quite new on here

Comment: @AlejandroI. There is a [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) about it. I am glad if my answer helped you. Good luck!

Comment: I think I did it.
I am bit confused about where I should add that line.
This is my restarter:

pidof service>/dev/null
PID1=$?
if [ $PID1 -eq 1 ]
 then
 screen -A -dmS service1 gdb --batch -x /home/server/crashreport.gdb /home/server/bin/service
fi

Where should I add that line?

Comment: @AlejandroI. I edited the answer. Can you confirm the TIME_WAIT socket scenario? Another possible reason might be that your service runs twice (you can check this with `pidof service` -- it should give you only one PID)...

Comment: Thanks a lot again, Vip.
The service does not run twice. I always check the services running using ps -A.
This service is made in C++, so when the service reachs a C++ error, it shuts down.
That is the moment when the socket this service uses, stays in a TIME_WAIT state for some minutes.
So, the restarter is faster and run the service causing the problem.
This problem is a open ticket in the original open source of this service, I am just looking for a "workaround" while this is fixed.

Thanks for helping a little person who is learning